# Как выключить вывод ошибок в OpenCart?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.0

Использую php 7 версию и Opencart 2. Но на сайте выводятся ошибки типа: "Устаревшая функция". Как их скрыть?

Добавил в .htaccess

```
php_value error_reporting 0
```

В index.php добавил:

```
   ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Толку ноль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выключите показ ошибок в админке (подходит для Opencart 2 и 3 версии):

Админка - Система - Настройки (там выберите свой магазин) - Вкладка "Сервер". Ищите там "Показывать ошибки" и ставите "Нет".

На самый крайний вариант через БД:

```
UPDATE setting SET `value` = 1 WHERE `key` = 'config_error_display'
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.